# trigonometric equation using compound angle formula

Tags: calculus

If $\arcsin (12/13) + \arccos (4/5) = \arcsin (k)$

Use the compound angle formula   $\sin(x+y) = \sin(x) \cos(y) + \cos(x) \sin(y)$
to find the exact value of k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $$\arcsin\frac{12}{13}=x\Rightarrow\sin x=12/13,\cos x=\sqrt{1-(12/13)^2}=5/13$$ and

$$ \arccos\frac{4}{5}=y\Rightarrow\cos y=4/5,\sin y=\sqrt{1-(4/5)^2}=3/5$$

then $$\sin (x+y)=\sin x\cos y+\sin y\cos x=\frac{12}{13}\frac{4}{5}+\frac{5}{13}\frac{3}{5}=\frac{63}{65}$$ then 
$$\arcsin \sin (x+y)=\arcsin \sin \frac{63}{65}=\arcsin k$$
$$k=\frac{63}{65}$$

Comment: Why $\sin y>0 \cos x>0$?

Answer (score 0):

let $\arcsin\dfrac{12}{13}=x$ and $ \arccos\dfrac45=y$

then $\sin x=\dfrac{12}{13}$ and $\cos y=\dfrac45$
then calculate $\cos x$ and $\sin y$ (in case the symbol)

and then get $\sin (x+y)$ then $\arcsin \sin (x+y)=\arcsin k$